# Toggling a file's "hidden" status

Tags: macos, command-line, automator

Using Automator, I want to be able to toggle a folder or file's "hidden" status. How is this possible through the command line? (I'm giving the file's directory to the script via a variable.)

Comment: Most files/folders with the hidden flag set are owned by root. This would not be a good idea to do in Automator.

Comment: @fd0, Maybe the target files/folders are owned by 1432 5876, not root, and while 1432 5876 hasn't stated on what files/folders it's to be used, nonetheless I see no issue with it being used in Automator if it does what is needed for the reason needed and in a safe manner so as not to effect the stability of the OS. Which is after all, up to 1432 5876 and no one else. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
chflags hidden /path/to/file
```

See also:  http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/19/hide-file-mac-os-x-chflags/

Comment: No idea why this down-voted as the answer is accurate. The link provides context, but the relevant part of it is copied into the answer.

Comment: @tubedogg I didn't, but I understand why it was downvoted. It's an incomplete answer. A good answer is (in pseudocode): if $path is visible then hide & else unhide